# Laravel. Валидация - поле может быть file или string или null

Tags: laravel, laravel5.4

Есть два правила которые нужно применить к одному полю. Если хотя бы один проходит - запрос валидный.

Пример который **не** работает:

```
class MyRequest extends FormRequest
// ...
   public function rules()
        {
            return [
                 'file' => 'image|max:20480',
                 'file' => 'nullable|string',
            ];
         }
}
```

*file* может быть **строкой**, **null** или **картинкой**. Помогите составить правило для использование в классе Request.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Тут к laravel мало отношения. только база. В данном коде у тебя будет работать только вторая строка.

```
class MyRequest extends FormRequest
    // ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             'file' => 'nullable|string|image|max:20480'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть правила через вертикальную черту и так все "или"?? Вот я протупил. Спасибо!

Comment: Беру свои слова обратно. Строку не пропускает.